# Terminal not using the last row

Tags: terminal

I just upgraded to High Sierra and started noticing a problem. When I open a new Terminal window, everything is fine. The output starts at the top and then fills the window. Eventually all rows are used (unless I run something like `clear`). This is the normal expected behavior. The problem is if I then open a new tab, the last row is not being utilized. It is always a blank line regardless of how much content is in the window.

If I go to `Preferences` > `Profiles` > `Window` and change the number of rows, the number of rows in the actual window changes (as expected) and the last row becomes useable again.

Comment: sounds like a bug that should be reported to Apple